# Counting words in a string input by the user

Tags: c++, string, manipulators

So I'm working on some review questions for the last chapter in my homework.

My question is, if a user inputs a string sentence, how would I go about counting the number of words?  I don't think it was covered in class, or will be covered in class.

I've gotten as far as requesting the sentence and using getline to read the string, but how would I go about counting the individual words other than writing the input to a file, opening the same file, and counting the words that way?

Comment: Pick the words as soon as you find space and newline in the string.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, because this is homework, but check the functions in `<string.h>`.  You basically want to find the next non-whitespace character in the string, then the next whitespace character, increment your counter, repeat until you reach the end of the string.

Comment: Actually, `<string.h>` is deprecated. Use `<string>` instead.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Either `<cstring>` or `<string.h>` are standard.  If you use the former, all the functions are declared in the `std::` namespace; if the latter, in the global namespace.

Comment: Really? Thanks, I thought they only existed for compatibility with C. Well, ignore my comment then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::istringstream` combined with `std::istream_iterator` to turn your string into the range of whitespace-separated tokens, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c).

To count the elements in range, just use `std::distance`.

I guess I won't provide the actual code since it's homework, but feel free to ask further.

Comment: Notice how the actual parsing will not happen until the call to `std::distance`. This may be a bit advanced, but it's kinda cool to pack all of your code into couple of library calls. Perhaps it would be a good practice to do it by hand at the same time just to keep track of what's going on though.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `str` is a `char *` which is the input sentence:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){
    while(i < strlen(str) && str[i] != ' ')
        i++;
    count++;
}
```

This is how you can do the counting manually without any special method of class `string.h`.

Comment: There are a couple of drawbacks though: it only considers `' '` to be a delimiter, and that's only one specific kind of whitespace; It counts the number of space characters, and it is very much not the same as the number of words.
 Besides it's more of a C code than C++, so you might as well stick with C to the end, like this:
`int count=1,i=0; while(str[i]) count+=(str[i++]==' ');`

Comment: Any loop that contains `strlen` in its condition is highly suspect.